# Star Trek Trexels: how many fights and effort are necessary to raise rank from Battle Group III to Battle Group IV?

Tags: star-trek-trexels

In Star Trek Trexels in the Android mobile platform, one the game's possibilities is a PVP fleet vs fleet game, where there are currently 5 ranks, and the ranks defines which ships and weapons you can acquire to fight
in the fleet vs fleet PVP game. If we start from Battle Group III, at 16,250 XP, how much (or how much effort) is actually needed to reach Battle Group IV?

Answer (score 1):

You start at 16,250 XP, where you attain BattleGroup III level, and must attain 101,250 XP to raise from BG III to BG IV level. Considering you need to gain 85,000 XP (which you cannot gain anywhere else except by gaining victories in PVP fleet vs fleet battles) and each victory grants you a number of non-fixed badge rewards but a 100 XP fixed award, you would need to win at least 850 fights to raise from BG III to BG IV, which is a considerable effort, because:

- if you lose you are dropped XP
- you will always need to repair ships, even if you win, because weapons do a large amount of damage at higher levels, where you can blow up a very powerful ship with just 2 cards, and you have 3 to play per turn
- you will always need to wait a certain amount of time to repair the ships (unless you have an endless supply of Dilithium, purchased for with real life money)
- you will spend a certain amount of time to find a player (granted, about 15 seconds, but still real time)
- spend time in the fight itself (each turn can take up to 30 seconds).

All in all, it's a considerable amount of real life time just to jump from this level to the next (still one to go, BG IV to BG V) so you should consider if you really want to waste time on the PVP and if it's not better just to stick to the Resource management / Ship Building / Main Adventure part of the game.